# MVC Ajax Post error

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I am getting error while I post Ajax request to controller method. In controller method I need to pass Model class object.
But it gives me 500 Internal server error.
Can anybody help me to make it correct?

Mu code is as per below:

```
jQuery:

 var request = $("#frmHost").serialize();


$.ajax({
        url: "/Host/HostItemDetails/" ,
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType : "application/json",
        data: request,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == '1111') {
                  ///Success code here
            }
            else if (data != '') {
                jAlert(data);
            }
        }
    });

Controller Method :
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult HostItemDetails(ClsHost objHost)
{
     //Code here
 return Json("1111");
}
```

Comment: your code looks perfectly fine. Can you share more details?

Comment: Yes sure. When I ran it, it will not called controller method.. and gives "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:1004/Host/HostItemDetails/"  And code is not executed.

Comment: Can I required to add any property on controller Method. Mean something like [HTTPPost]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nirav Try this,

Parse the serialized data as a JSON object and later stringify that while posting using JSON.stringify().

```
$("#Button").click(function () {
       var data = $("#frmHost").serialize().split("&");
       var request = {};
       for (var key in data) {
            request[data[key].split("=")[0]] = data[key].split("=")[1];
       }

       $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/HostItemDetails/",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            success: function (data) {
               if (data == '1111') {
                  ///Success code here
               }
               else if (data != '') {
                  jAlert(data);
               }
            }
      });
  });
```

Comment: Its useful as I am getting response data in below format name "test" name1 "test2" like that. But still same 500 internal server error.

Comment: Can you please show me how the Model ClsHost looks.

Comment: Its look like
 public partial class ClsHost : IClsHost
    {
 
        
        #region "Property Of Host Item Details "
        public long lgHostItemDetailsId { get; set; }
        public long lgHostId { get; set; }
        public long lgItemId { get; set; }
        public string strItemName { get; set; }
        public List<ClsHost> listHostItemDetails { get; set; }
        
        public decimal? dcCostPerWeek { get; set; }
        public string strComment { get; set; }
        #endregion
}

Comment: You have to build the JSON Object rather than serializing the form, according to your model. JSON has to contain a Json Array as a value for  listHostItemDetails parameter. The json should be in this format. stringify this while posting. var data = {  "lgHostId":value_Of_lgHostID, "lgItemId": value_Of_lgItemId, "strItemName": value_of_strItemName,  "listHostItemDetails": [  {  "lgHostId": value_Of_lgHostID, "lgItemId": value_Of_lgItemId, "strItemName": value_of_strItemName   },  { "lgHostId": value_Of_lgHostID, "lgItemId": value_Of_lgItemId, "strItemName": value_of_strItemName } ] }

Comment: Hello Vinod, Thanks for your answer on this. I solved it by removing property name in Model Class. It is added twice mistakenly by me. But very thankful to you for sharing Idea and your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same code that you are running.
To test the code I did the following changes. I took a button, and on click event I am sending the post back to the controller.
the '[HttpPost]' attribute is fine too.

Can you make one thing sure, that the frmHost data matches to the class ClsHost,but still that shouldn't cause the server error, the error will be different.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickMe").click(function () {
        var request = '{"Users":[{"Name":"user999","Value":"test"},{"Name":"test2","Value":"test"}]}';
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/HostItemDetails/",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: request,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == '1111') {
                    ///Success code here
                }
                else if (data != '') {
                    jAlert(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult HostItemDetails(ClsHost objHost)
{
    //Code here
    return Json("111", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
}
```

Comment: Ok let me check it again. Thanks.

Comment: I checked that frmHost data matches to the class ClsHost. But  I think error coming is different. Is there any other suggestion to solve it?

Comment: try to add "[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" too on your controller and return "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" parameter as well

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the Controller method, what do u get in objHost?? did u set JsonRequestBehavoiur.AllowGet??

Comment: Controller method does not called after putting the things those are suggested by you. Also I would like to know you that in jquery I am posting the request and that request data string is like

Comment: "lgId=0&strHostName=&lgStatusId=&strHomeAddress1=&strAddress2=&strCity=&strPostCode=&strState=&lgCountryID=&lgRegionID=&strHomePhone=&lgHostItemDetailsId=0&lgItemId=1&dcCostPerWeek=&strComment=&lgHostQuestionDetailsId=0&lgQuestionId=&dcFloat=&strText=&dtDateTime=&lgHostNameDetailsId=0&lgStatusId=&strFirstName=&strSurName=&dtDOB=&strNationality=&lgCountryID=&lgLanguageID=&strOccupation=&strBlueCardNum=&dtBlueCardExpiry=&strPhoneSMS=&strEmail=&blIsPrimaryContact=false&strRelationToPrimary="

Comment: Hello Newton,Thanks for your answer on this. I solved it by removing property name in Model Class. It is added twice mistakenly by me. But very thankful to you for sharing Idea and your knowledge with me.

Comment: Thank you all for spending time to suggest way to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by removing same property name in Model class. It is mistakenly added by me twice.